# Об Алексиевич - первой после Бродского

Tags: пунктуация

Светлана Алексиевич стала первым писателем из Белоруссии, получившим Нобелевскую премию по литературе, и первым автором, пишущим по-русски - после Иосифа Бродского.

Нужна ли запятая после *по-русски?*

Answer (score 3):

Нужна. Она ставится для закрытия причастного оборота, а тире относится к конструкции "первым... - после". Поэтому последнее (тире) первую (запятую) не исключает, её нужно сохранить.

Answer (score 1):

> > и первым автором, пишущим по-русски - после Иосифа Бродского

Как это – "первым после"? Тогда уж не первым, а вторым. И это если не считать Бунина, Шолохова и Солженицына.

Comment: А первый кто? Niemand, что у вас у мысль зашкаливает. Вы хоть бы для себя уяснили, когда жил Бунин и когда - Бродский. Бунин никак не мог быть **после** Бродского. И Бродский после Бродского - тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, но, как уже здесь указано, **семантика предложения неясна и кажется неверной,** его надо переделать.

**В качестве варианта:** Светлана Алексиевич стала первым писателем из Белоруссии, получившим Нобелевскую премию по литературе, а с 1987 года, после Иосифа Бродского,  - первым автором, пишущим по-русски.